# Stripe Payment Gateway error with GiveWP, "Unable to create a payment intent"

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I installed GiveWP – Donation Plugin on my website. I create the form and configured Stripe payment gateway. When I try to make a donation I get this message:

> **Error:** Error creating payment intent with Stripe. Please try again.
>
> **Error:** Unhandled payment intent status:

Then I checked the error log on GiveWP plugin and found this:

```
{
    "post_title": "Stripe Payment Intent Error",
    "post_content": "Unable to create a payment intent. Details: Amount must be at least $0.50 usd",
    "post_parent": 0,
    "log_type": "gateway_error",
    "file": "/home/directory/public_html/wp-content/plugins/give/includes/gateways/functions.php",
    "line": 260,
    "function": "add",
    "class": "Give_Logging"
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Can anybody help?

Comment: What amount did you specify in your Stripe Payment. You know that Stripe payments are in **cent** so if you want to pay `$0.50` your value of your payment intent would be `50` [cent] ? Please [read the Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents).

Comment: You are right. When I try $500 and make a test donation it's donated USD 5. But on my form I have $500.00, $1000.00 etc buttons. So how can a donar donate $500.00 Here is a screenshot link of my form: https://prnt.sc/CCCJX6IKXLIA

Comment: If you follow the GiveWP or Stripe documentation it should do this for you; for example to donate $500.00 it would be: `\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 50000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
]);` in the Stripe PHP Payment Intent code